# R Objects do not exist (undefined), but R can retrieve values

Tags: r, object, undefined, plyr

I am having trouble trying to generate a table using ddply:

```
ddply(Data, .(Data$Condition), summarise, n = length(Data$Condition), 
      mean = mean(Data$Composite), std = sd(Data$Composite), var = var(Data$Composite))
```

The following error comes up:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(col, i) : undefined columns selected
```

However, the columns in my df that I am trying to use in the ddply are clearly defined. I also tested this in R, apparently R:

- Can retrieve their values
- Knows their data class
- Data$Condition is apparently an object, Data$Composite is not an object
- Both columns do not exist according to exists()

Please see the code and outcome below:

> Data$Condition
> [1] HIGH   MEDIUM LOW    LOW    HIGH
> Levels: HIGH LOW MEDIUM ZERO

> Data$Composite
> [1] 5.454545 3.545455 5.545455 5.818182 5.272727

> data.class(Data$Condition)
> [1] "factor"

> data.class(Data$Composite)
> [1] "numeric"

> is.object(Data$Condition)
> [1] TRUE

> is.object(Data$Composite)
> [1] FALSE

> exists(Data$Condition)
> Error in exists(Data$Condition) : invalid first argument

> exists(Data$Composite)
> Error in exists(Data$Composite) : invalid first argument

To make things even stranger, the following code works without problems:

```
Data %>%
group_by(Condition) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(Composite), funs(mean(., na.rm=TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue. I can run your code on your data with no error using `plyr` version 1.8.6. However, the result is probably not what you want. I get the same mean, std, and var for all three values of Condition.

This is what I think you want:

```
ddply(Data, "Condition", summarise, n = length(Composite), 
      mean = mean(Composite), std = sd(Composite), var = var(Composite))

  Condition n     mean       std        var
1      HIGH 2 5.363636 0.1285649 0.01652893
2       LOW 2 5.681818 0.1928473 0.03719008
3    MEDIUM 1 3.545455        NA         NA
```

By always putting `Data$Composite` in the calls to the functions, you are always using all values in `Data$Composite` instead of those based on the column condition that `ddply` splits on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is the most weird error I have ever come across in R. Like you mentioned, I can also use the code without problems when I export that part of the df and run it in another df. I have used your code and now I have the following error: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'HIGH' not found

Answer (score 0):

ddply did not work with this df, because according to ddply my columns did not exist: ("undefined columns selected"). So I tried to work around it, using another function to create a table:

```
Data %>%
  select(Condition, Composite) %>%
  group_by(Condition) %>%
  summarise_all(list(mean = mean, sd = sd, var = var), na.rm=TRUE)
```

This function did work, although it is less intuitive to use. This has been the weirdest error I have come across in R.